# My own binary in debug mode "Binary was not built with debug information"

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.6 on Win10

When I try to debug my application with break points, I see "The breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.".
I checked Debug > Windows > Modules and found "Binary was not built with debug information.". This is only the case for my application, all references and system DLL's are loaded.

I have ensured "Debug Info" is set to Full.
I have tried deleting my Bin and Obj folder and rebuilding. 
My profile is set to "Debug"".

Just in case this might be my code, I tried this and "Symbol File Not Loaded":

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
```

I've also noticed that the PDB file is being made, even after deleting/rebuilding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the Assembly Name.

It contains whitespace, meaning for some reason the PDB wouldn't load. Removing whitespace solved the problem.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please [mark your reply as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see the option originally, turns out I was logged out at the time!